# Excel VSTO app code signing certificate expiring, can we renew without a new deployment?

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

I inherited an Excel VSTO app that, three years ago, was signed with a certificate that is now expiring. We'd like to extend or update it without a new application deployment (not having to re-sign from within Visual Studio). Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your signature has timestamp, there is no need to re-sign or re-deploy the application at all (the signature with timestamp will not expire even after the certificate expires). If your signature does not have timestamp, you will have to re-sign and re-deploy the application.