# VSTO Excel add-in not working after Expiry date of certificate which used to signing

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce, code-signing, signing

I am using VSTO in my project with WPF.
I am signing my exe,addin dll,msi,installer using pfx file which having expiry on june-23-2021.I am  time stamping using digicert.But after expiry of certificate addin is not working.

i checked by below method:
When i change my system clock after expiry date of certificate , addin is not loading.
But if i time stamped,it has to work properly.

I tried from below link but it didnt work for me:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc16e9bf-8628-4abf-95e9-d1e38633730d/vsto-3-addin-not-using-timestamp-on-expired-certificate?forum=vsto

I tried below methods ,but that also didnt work.
method 1:

```
signtool sign /f mycertpfx.pfx /p passwd /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com/?alg=sha256 /td sha256 /fd sha256 /d "myexe.exe"
```

method 2:

```
signtool sign /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /f "mycertpfx.pfx" /p passwdr "myexe.exe"
signtool sign /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /f "mycertpfx.pfx" /p passwdr "myaddin.dll"
signtool sign /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /f "mycertpfx.pfx" /p passwdr "mymsi.msi"
signtool sign /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /f "mycertpfx.pfx" /p passwdr "myinstaller.exe"
```

method 3:

```
signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /f  "mycertpfx.pfx" /p passwdr "myexe.exe"
signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /f  "mycertpfx.pfx" /p passwdr "myaddin.dll"
signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /f  "mycertpfx.pfx" /p passwdr "mymsi.msi"
signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /f  "mycertpfx.pfx" /p passwdr "myinstaller.exe"
```

Need solution for the above issue.

Also need a method to check a click once (excel adding vsto) will work ,even after the expiry of certificate.(like system clock changing)

IDE: Visual studio 2017

[image: Screenshot attached about the error showing after expiry date]

Comment: _"...When i change my system clock"_ - that makes your post a bit dubious...particularly for a `HP Inc` add-in

Comment: @MickyD "HP Inc" is just a directory created for installing. My issue is ,after expiry of certificate, excel addin wont work.

Comment: _"after expiry of certificate, excel addin wont work"_ - that is `by design`

Comment: @MickyD if we create an excel addin by signing and timestamping, addin has to work even after expiry of signing certificate.

Comment: @MickyD refere:https://www.digicert.com/kb/code-signing/signcode-signtool-command-line.htm

Comment: If the certificate has expired or is invalid (which the screenshot shows) then _how did you manage to sign the VSTO add-in?_ Surely you would have gotten an error there.  If so it is pointless to try and install it in Excel

Comment: _["The certificates used to sign ClickOnce applications **expire after a certain length of time**, typically twelve months. In order to remove the need to constantly re-sign applications with new certificates, ClickOnce supports **timestamp**. When an application is signed with a timestamp, its certificate will continue to be accepted **even after expiration**, provided the timestamp is valid.This allows ClickOnce applications with expired certificates, but valid timestamps, to download and run"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-and-authenticode?view=vs-2019)_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185816/excel-vsto-app-code-signing-certificate-expiring-can-we-renew-without-a-new-dep

Comment: @MickyD  I am time stamping using digisert.  while creating installer
"signtool sign /tr timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a "c:\path\to\file.exe" ". I have mentioned in Method1,2,3. 
As per Digicert it has to work..I changed the system date To check if this is working.But addin is not working after the expiry date of my certificate.Need a method to check this is working or not. Above links didnt solved my issue.Thanks for the link.

Comment: _"But addin is `not working after` the `expiry date` of my certificate"_ - good. Then what's the problem?  None of what you are saying makes sense.  If you want your add-in to never expire then look at my first link.  QED

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231629/discussion-between-mickyd-and-sudeep).